# Website Information using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a bibliography application using c# windows forms. I have a panel for web-page source details and a button near the url so that when the user press this button, I can retrieve information like the 'Year Modified', the 'author' of the page etc.. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Go back to the questions you asked previously, and accept an answer for each.

Comment: Mark, accept an answer some of your questions, which do you want

Comment: Accept the answers that you find helpful. For every answer on your question, you will find a 'tick' mark. Just click on that. This will tell the community which answer worked for you.

Comment: @Mark Click you name on the top of page and accept a few answers (click the big Check Mark) for the questions you asked in the past, this is the way you say thanks to the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve the webpage content like

```
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string url = "http://www.google.com";
string result = null;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    result = client.DownloadString( url );
```

Later on you can then find out the required info.

Comment: is there a way to get specific text from page not looping through the string

Comment: You could get the string on some criteria using regular expression.

Comment: the problem of the above code is that not every page will have the last modified date... and I need to get this info

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not very clear... I assume that you want to extract the information from web page. You need to know the structure of the page and then parse the HTML. You may look for the specific items such as a label or text box with the name *author* for example.

Comment: Instead of typing in the date modified, the name of the page, etc.. I need to do this automatically...

Comment: did you down rated my question... cause it is very useful and clear

Comment: No I did not down rate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), (Find the specific XML you want using the [Firebug Addon](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox), then run some code along these lines:

```
    private void PageScrape(string url)
    {
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(url);
        var date = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class='Article_Date']");
            if (date != null)
            {
               goodBox.Text += date.InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
               goodBox.Text += "whoops!";
            }
        }
```

If you have a specific website I can give you a more specific code example.

Comment: For example, this url: http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Pulling-Data-From-Internet-URLs-in-C/
how can i get the date modified, not the year only but the day,month, year

Comment: @Mark try my updated code, I got the path I believe you wanted placed in there as .//*[@class='Article_Date'], which will find the date and the rating of the article, but you can parse that out if need be. I didn't run the code, but it should work fine.